# Django upload doc to S3 and generate PDF preview

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I'm currently using Django regular upload. After a doc is uploaded, a celery task is executed to get it converted to PDF using libreoffice. Both files are publicly accessible on /media.

Now I want to start using S3 to store my files and make them private. Here are my options:

1. Upload doc to S3. Then have the celery task connect to S3, download the file, convert to PDF, upload and delete from local storage.
2. Upload doc to regular storage, then have the celery task make the conversion, upload both files to S3 and then delete.

Restriction: the S3 bucket is not public. I'm planning on authenticating the user before downloading, and then redirecting to the bucket with a temporary valid access key.

Do I have any other options? I haven't actually tried this yet, but it seems I'm going to need multiple django storages if I choose 2., one for uploading (local) and one for downloading (S3). Is this even possible?

Comment: I've voted to close, not because it's a bad question, but because it should be broken up into a few different questions.

Comment: On a side note, if you're planning to delete things from local storage when you upload to S3, it makes me think your local file system is ephemeral (e.g., Heroku). If that's the case, it will only be a matter of time before you lose a local file before conversion, leading to data loss, and an almost immediate certainty that you'll run into problems with horizontal scaling. The ideal solution would ideally work from S3, falling back to local storage when S3 objects aren't yet created. Take a look at http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. It'll help you either way.

Comment: You're right. Uploading to S3 seems to be the right way. Then I have to deal with the problem of downloading/converting/upload PDF on the background using celery, like you said, a separate question, but I wanted to know if this was the correct approach before proceeding.

Comment: It depends on the situation (i.e., use your best judgement, and don't fall for any dogmas), but typically converting something to a PDF, which is computationally intensive (relative to querying a DB and returning bytes of HTML, etc.) should be handled in Celery. So, your UX will have to be designed to handle the workflow of 1) upload doc, 2) be told it will be ready shortly, 3) either update the page via Ajax (or something more hip than that), or email the user when their PDF is ready, and 4) checking whether the PDF is ready in a page that would normally display the PDF.

Comment: The model for such would probably contain a field for the uploaded file, and a preview field. Don't make either of the file fields null (see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10244). Just make them `blank=True`, if they're optional (which the preview will have to be, since it won't be populated at first).